# Supplying command line options to a packaged electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a couple scripts set up in package.json to switch between command line options for my electron app

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron . kira",
    "kira": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron . kira",
    "mia": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron . mia",
    "cybertech": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron . cybertech",
    "package": "node ./scripts/package.js",
},
```

However after packaging I am not sure how to use these command line switches. Ideally I would like to set up a command like `npm run package-cybertech` that would set up My_App.exe to execute with the "cybertech" flag added.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look in [Pass arguments to packaged electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731875/pass-arguments-to-packaged-electron-application)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I have read about the issues with the order of command line arguments being different in packaged and unpackaged versions. But I guess I am asking about supplying default arguments to packaged apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of packaged source of electron app, command line arguments can be accessed using following function. Let's say if we have passed the command line argument as `--arg=value`. It can be retrieved like this in the **main.js**:

```
import { app } from "electron";
app.commandLine.getSwitchValue("arg");
```

To check if default argument is present (without any value):

```
app.commandLine.hasSwitch("arg")
```

This works for development mode as well.