# How to pass an argument to electron when using electron-builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I'm building an application with Electron and packaging with Electron Builder. When running electron, I want to pass this [command line argument: --enable-mixed-sandbox](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/sandbox-option.md).

Is it possible? How?

This:

```
 app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-mixed-sandbox')
```

wouldn't work [due to](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/sandbox-option.md#example):

> Note that it is not enough to call
>   app.commandLine.appendSwitch('--enable-sandbox'), as electron/node
>   startup code runs after it is possible to make changes to chromium
>   sandbox settings. The switch must be passed to electron on the
>   command-line:
>
> ```
> electron --enable-sandbox app.js
> ```
>
> It is not possible to have the OS sandbox active only for some renderers, if --enable-sandbox is enabled, normal electron windows
>   cannot be created.

Comment: I suppose the easiest way is to edit the shortcut so that it launches with that option. Not sure how to do that programmatically though.

Comment: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1905

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake those arguments don't reach electron as far as I know. Do you know otherwise?

Comment: Try it manually and see what happens?

Comment: I've changed my answer substantially.

Answer (score 0):

`enable-mixed-sandbox` is not a valid Electron command line flag. See [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/command-line-switches) for all available command line flags for Electron.

Answer (score -1):

I got [a response](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1905) on that issue I raised and linked to in the comments:

```
app.enableMixedSandbox() // Experimental macOS Windows
```

See [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appenablemixedsandbox-experimental-macos-windows) for documentation.

Answer (score -1):

another way of doing it, you can use spectron to start the app in debug mode. which allows you to pass any arguments you want.

```js
const Application = require('spectron').Application

// Returns a promise that resolves to a Spectron Application once the app has loaded.
// Takes a Ava test. Makes some basic assertions to verify that the app loaded correctly.
function createApp (t) {
  return new Application({
    path: 'path/to/app',
    args: ['-r', '--enable-mixed-sandbox'],
    env: {NODE_ENV: 'test'},
    waitTimeout: 10e3
  })
}
```

https://github.com/electron/spectron#new-applicationoptions

Comment: How does that work with electron builder to distribute apps? I can pass whatever argument I want in dev mode, that's not the issue. The issue is the .exe generated by electron-builder.

Comment: well I don't think you can pass sandbox for bundled app because of security concerns. as electron mentioned in docs _Some bug in V8 engine may allow malicious code to access the renderer preload APIs, effectively granting full access to the system through the remote module._

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742370/6942552) as well might explain a bit more.